# Oracle SQL group data by value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this tables:

```
TABLE_A

ID | ATTR_NAME | ATTR_ID | START_DATE
-------------------------------------
1  | XPTA      | 12      | 01-10-2013
1  | XPTO      | 167     | 01-10-2013
1  | XPTA      | 13      | 04-12-2013
2  | XPTA      | 12      | 03-09-2015
2  | XPTO      | 6       | 05-08-2012

TABLE_B (just to help understand)

ATTR_NAME | ATTR_ID | DESCRIPTION
---------------------------------
XPTA      | 12      | ASM5
XPTO      | 167     | weird attr
XPTA      | 13      | DBSO12
XPTO      | 6       | gosh...
```

Is there a way to make a select return this?

```
ID | XPTA | XPTO | START_DATE
-----------------------------
1  | 12   | 167  | 01-10-2013
1  | 13   |      | 04-12-2013
2  | 12   |      | 03-09-2015
2  |      | 6    | 05-08-2012
```

Basically, the COL1 represents an attribute and COL2 the id value of COL1 associated to the ID starting from START_DATE
Example: Resource Mike (ID) has a cost profile (COL1) of ASM5 (COL2) starting from 01-10-2013 (START_DATE)

The ideia is to group the attributes by date for each ID.

The only way I see I can do it e first do a **select start_date distinct from TABLE_A** and then for each date fetched do a **select ID, COL1, COL2, :date_start from TABLE_A where START_DATE = :date_start** and then somehow make COL1 values my columns and COL2 values my values.

Comment: I assume the 6 in the last row of the desired results should be in the third column, not the second.

Comment: You are completely right. I'm sorry for the mistake. Correction made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you're looking for conditional aggregation, something you can do with `max` and `case`:

```
select id, 
    max(case when attr_name = 'XPTA' then attr_id end) xpta,
    max(case when attr_name = 'XPTO' then attr_id end) xpto,
    start_date
from table_a 
group by id, start_date
```

Comment: Thank You @sgedded, this is much simplier than I would think of. I still find awkward this line of thought but I think I understand it.